# Why does the UrlOpener in Python Take ages to return

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

So i recently have been working on a program to check the availability of usernames on a website i have the core program done but when it searches each name it takes almost 2 seconds a name. any ideas on ways to increase efficiency?

```
    def urlTest(name):

        opener = URLopener() #Open the URL Connection
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        page = opener.open("https://exampleusernamechecker.com/s?"+str(name)) #Open the page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

        ABC=soup.find_all("div",class_="alert-link")

        if "Available" in str(ABC):
            print( "Success")
            file = open("Freenames.txt","at")
            file.write(""+str(name)+"\n")
            file.close()

        else:
            print("Failure",ABC)
        opener.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new connection for every name, a 2 second delay is to be expected.

If you want to speed up things, create and reuse a single connection.

If you want to speed it more, read many pages at a time, you can't do anything about delay/latency, but you can increase throughput/use more bandwidth.

Comment: Reusing a single connection is impossible though, if i am using a s?method to search as the website uses this "/s?wordhere" to search for username can you point me to a way that can reuse a connection when i have to do this each time?

Comment: Define your opener on a class level and reuse it?